# Prove that an underdetermined system of cannot have a unique solution(Is this proof correct?)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I know I misspelled underdetermine but is this proof correct? How can I improve it either way?

[image]

Side Remark: Anyone who is down-voting please can you understand I new to this site and somewhat anxious. I wouldn't mind the down vote but they are threating to close my account. I don't see why a down vote is waranted unless I was deliberately wasting time or it must be that this community doesn't encourage learning.

Comment: I'm not sure what the situation regarding downvotes was, but if you have any questions regarding the non-mathematical goings on of the site, you can ask them on the [meta SE site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is mostly correct, but you're missing an important piece.

You've accurately stated that, if the system is consistent, then (because of the presence of basic variables) there are infinitely many solutions.  You should additionally say that if the system is *inconsistent*, then there by definition is *no* solution, and so we still can't have a unique solution.